# Bottom (xaxis) line of Highcharts graph should disappear

Tags: highcharts, axis

I have no idea why the bottom horizontal line of my Highcharts graph shows a line (highlighted below in the screenshot). It shouldn't be there...

Guess there is an easy trick to get rid of it? I haven't found though the solution...

[image]

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    enabled: false,
    style: {
      color: "#666666"
    },
    x: 0
  },
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  gridLineDashStyle: 'Dot',
  tickWidth: 0
},
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/LppLL158/2/).

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the axis line. You can set the width of it to zero:

```
xAxis: {
    lineWidth: 0,
    // ...
}
```

See [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LppLL158/3/) and [the API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.lineWidth).

Comment: I knew it would be simple... Thanks a lot!